# Valid type casting of both covariant and contravariant class at runtime in Scala

Tags: scala, types, covariance, contravariance

I wrote a class implementing the [command design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

```
class MyCommand[-T, +R](val name: String, val execute: T => R)
```

, prepared two command and stored it in a MutableList:

```
val commands = new mutable.MutableList[MyCommand[Nothing, Any]]
commands += new MyCommand[String, String]("lower", s => s.toLowerCase())
commands += new MyCommand[Date, Long]("time", d => d.getTime)
```

Then I have two data to be executed:

```
val data = Array("StRiNG", new Date())
```

The problem for me is that I don't know how to determine which datum is applicable to the command:

```
data.foreach {
  d => commands.foreach {
    c =>
    // println(c.execute(d)) if d is applicable to c.execute().
  }
}
```

what I tried is pattern matching with type specification, but it yields syntax error:

```
c.execute match {
  case m: (d.getClass => Any) => println(c.execute(d))
}
```

Help me :(

Comment: Please state your specific problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I proposed a solution which actually didn't work as I expected. Can you clarify where the data is coming from? I think that when you need to use Nothing there is something really strange going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there are better ways of solving this problem, but this might work for you. I tested it with Scala 2.9.2.

`MyCommand` takes a `Manifest` as an additional implicit argument, which gives us access to the class that represents the from-type of the `execute` function at runtime:

```
class MyCommand[-T: Manifest, +R](val name: String, val execute: T => R) {
  val fromClass = manifest[T].erasure
}
```

The list of commands is basically as in your original post, as is the list of data:

```
val commands = List(
  new MyCommand[String, String]("lower", _.toLowerCase()),
  new MyCommand[Date, Long]("time", _.getTime)
)

val data = List("StRiNG", new Date())
```

Matching data to commands relies on the runtime representation of the involved types as classes, and a rather ugly cast. The cast is especially ugly because it does not give a precise return type, i.e., additional matches or casts are necessary if you need to know the precise return type of the command's return value.

```
data foreach { d =>
  commands foreach { c =>
    println("data: %s (%s), command takes: %s"
           .format(d, d.getClass.getSimpleName, c.fromClass.getSimpleName))

    if (d.getClass.isAssignableFrom(c.fromClass)) {
      println("    cmd(data) = " + c.execute.asInstanceOf[Any => Any](d))
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
data: StRiNG (String), command takes: String
    cmd(data) = string
data: StRiNG (String), command takes: Date
data: Sun Aug 05 14:46:17 CEST 2012 (Date), command takes: String
data: Sun Aug 05 14:46:17 CEST 2012 (Date), command takes: Date
    cmd(data) = 1344170777681
```

Comment: Great! I didn't thought about using Manifest. It works perfect! Thank you.