# abstracting scala case class's copy method with a parameter

Tags: scala

I need to abstract the copy method generated by Scala compiler for case classes with its parameters. In my case, I have a save method like below

```
def save[T<:Data](data:T):T={
// store in db and get the id
  val dbId = ...
  data.copy(dbId)
}
```

and a set of case classes like below

```
trait Data
case class Foo (id:Option[Int] = None,name:String,age:Int) extends Data
case class Bar (id:Option[Int] = None, name:String,address:String) extends Data
```

How can I abstract the copy method, any alternative solution would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do this with macros in Scala 2.10—see for example my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13447439/334519).

Comment: The generated `copy` method has no parameters, please clarify.

Comment: You can introduce a trait that has id and then make a save method for this trait, and extend your table representations with it.

Comment: Actually, the case-class `copy` method has exactly the same parameters as the construct, it's just that they're all optional. Any that *are* supplied are used to make the copy different from the original (otherwise there's little reason to copy an immutable value...).