# scala macros: defer type inference

Tags: scala, macros, inference

Preamble: this is based on @Travis Brown's [macro based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447439/185840) to copying case class properties.

Given:

```
trait Entity[E <: Entity[E]]{self:E=>
  def id: Int
  def withId(id: Int) = MacroCopy.withId(self,id)
}
case class User(id: Int, name: String) extends Entity[User]
```

and the Macro implementation:

```
object MacroCopy {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
  def withId[T](entity: T, id: Int): T = macro withIdImpl[T]

  def withIdImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag]
    (c: Context)(entity: c.Expr[T], id: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[T] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tree = reify(entity.splice).tree
    val copy = entity.actualType.member(TermName("copy"))

    val params = copy match {
      case s: MethodSymbol if (s.paramLists.nonEmpty) => s.paramLists.head
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "No eligible copy method!")
    }
    c.Expr[T](Apply(
      Select(tree, copy),
      AssignOrNamedArg(Ident(TermName("id")), reify(id.splice).tree) :: Nil
    ))
  }
}
```

is there a way to somehow defer type inference in such a way that the macro operates on a `User` and not the Entity's self type? As it stands the type checker knows nothing about the `User`'s case class copy method since all it sees is a value of type `E`.

I'd like to do:

```
val u = User(2,"foo")
u.withId(3)
```

Most of the alternative solutions I've seen entail defining withId as abstract in the Entity trait and then implementing the method in *every* case class, would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this in detail at the moment, but have you seen [this blog post of mine](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/21/macro-methods-and-subtypes/)?

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks, that got me a step further, now can do `u.withId(u,3)`. Looks like context bound is the way to go to avoid having to pass in the instance you already have. Will give it a go in the AM...

Comment: Btw a question about your post, @TravisBrown. Why not use c.prefix.tree.tpe there?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako because linked solution is from 2012? Speaking of the past, should one take a significantly different approach to the problem with scala 2.11 macros? Got deprecation warnings with Travis' original code.

Comment: Non-backportable changes to macros in Scala 2.11 are quite few (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/changelog211.html). Most of the stuff is either the same or are available in compatible fashion. Deprecation warnings are just hints - it should be okay to leave them in code for now.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako got it down to u.withId(3), but have hit a roadblock trying to apply withId in parent trait (see my answer below). So I don't waste any more time on this, is such a thing possible with macros or is the concrete instance required?

Comment: I don't think you can make `update` do what you want without turning it into a macro itself. If you want to abstract over macros, you need to do it with macros.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako thanks, I've gone back to plain old `u.copy(_:Int)`, will revisit this when scala.meta comes on the stage. Perhaps some combination of the solution here and macro annotations can capture enough type information and/or delay inferred type. Looking forward to the next round of macro madness regardless, fun stuff ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`weakTypeOf` combined with a context bound on instance's class provides desired "delayed" type inference.

```
trait Entity[E <: Entity[E]]{self:E=>
  def id: Int
  def withId(id: Int) = MacroCopy.withIdImpl[E]
}
case class User(id: Int, name: String) extends Entity[User]

object MacroCopy {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

  def withIdImpl[T <: Entity[T]: c.WeakTypeTag] // context bound on Entity
    (c: Context)(id: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[T] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tree = reify( c.Expr[T](c.prefix.tree).splice ).tree
    val copy = weakTypeOf[T].member(TermName("copy")) // now lookup case class' copy method
    val params = copy match {
      case s: MethodSymbol if (s.paramLists.nonEmpty) => s.paramLists.head
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "No eligible copy method!")
    }
    c.Expr[T](Apply(
      Select(tree, copy),
      AssignOrNamedArg(Ident(TermName("id")), reify(id.splice).tree) :: Nil
    ))
  }
}
```

We can now write `foo.withId(2)` in place of previous attempt, `foo.withId(foo, 2)`, wonderfully concise. Might be wondering why not just do: `foo.copy(id = 2)`? For the concrete case that works fine, but when you need to apply this at a more abstract level, then it works not at all.

The following also does not work, seems we must work with concrete case classes instances, so close ;-( <s>For example, let's say you have a DAO and you want to ensure that all updated entities have a valid id. The above macro allows you to do something like:</s>

```
def update[T <: Entity[T]](entity: T, id: Int)(implicit ss: Session): Either[String,Unit] = {
  either( byID(id).mutate(_.row = entity.withId(id)), i18n("not updated") )
}
```

Since Entity is a trait and not a case class, without the macro there would be no compile-time way of simulating an `entity.copy(id = id)`. As a workaround I have redefined DAO update method as follows:

```
def update[T <: Entity[T]](fn: id => T, id: Int)(implicit ss: Session): Either[String,Unit] = {
  either( byID(id).mutate(_.row = fn(id)), i18n("not updated") )
}
```

That at least forces one to supply u.withId(_:Int) function to the update method. Better than having potentially invalid entities at runtime, but still not as elegant as performing withId right before it matters (i.e. persisting to DB), thereby avoiding the mule work (boilerplate) of passing concrete function instance to update, sigh, there must be a way to pull this off with macros.

In other news, having written my first macro, I am really liking the potential here, awesome stuff ;-)