# how to copy instance and override value field declared in trait

Tags: scala

Suppose I have some abstract value field defined in a trait:

```
trait Base {
  val toBeOverride: String
}

case class Impl(other:Int) extends Base {
  override val toBeOverride = "some value"
}
```

How can I write a function that I can easily get a cloned instance only overriding the `toBeOverride` value, like this:

```
// copy only available to case class instance
// v does not have method 'copy'
def overrideBaseValue[T <: Base](v: Base) = 
    v.copy(toBeOverride = "prefix" + v.toBeOverride)
```

?

**Edit**

@som-snytt, I don't think this is a duplicate, just like a `Trait` is not the same as an `Abstract Class`. And the answers of that question do not satisfy me, see below.

@Blaisorblade, yes, it is a problem. For instances of each sub case class, the `toBeOverride` field are the same, so it should not appear in the constructor.

For now all the suggestions are to define an customized `copy` method in each(!) sub case class and that in my opinion is ugly and shows the incapability of the language.

Comment: Do you need the case class? Can you just create a new instance of the Base trait with the toBeOverride method overriden. Like this: `def overrideBaseValue(v: Base) = new Base {def  toBeOverride = "prefix" + v.toBeOverride }`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370244/case-class-copy-method-with-superclass

Comment: @rjsvaljean, yes, when I say "copy" I want to preserve all the other fields of the case class instances, e.g. `other` in the example.

Comment: @ziggystar Please, humiliate me with **facts**, shut me up with **solutions**.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just add the method you want to Base:

```
trait Base {
  val toBeOverride: String
  def copyBase(newToBeOverridden: String): Base
}

case class Impl(other:Int, override val toBeOverride: String = "some value") extends Base {
  def copyBase(newToBeOverridden: String) = copy(toBeOverride = newToBeOverridden)
}
```

This also allows to directly create an instance of `Impl` while specifying the value of `toBeOverride` (which wasn't possible). The only disadvantage is that now pattern matches using Impl have to change syntax - please update your question and add a comment if that's a problem.

BTW, if you just want to add a prefix (as in your example), that's no problem:

```
case class Impl(other:Int, override val toBeOverride: String = "some value") extends Base {
  def copyBase(newToBeOverridden: String) = copy(toBeOverride = toBeOverride + newToBeOverridden)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two mechanisms.

Apparently, in the near future you'll be able to write a macro that can emit the anonymous subclass, but until then, I think this typeclass is not arduous.

Just kicking the tires on Dynamic here.

```
import scala.language.dynamics
import scala.reflect._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ currentMirror => cm }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Base {
  def m: String
}
case class Impl(p: Int) extends Base {
  override val m = "some value"
}

trait Basic extends Dynamic {
  protected def m: String
  def selectDynamic(f: String): Any =
    if ("m" == f) m else reflecting(this, f)
  protected def reflecting(b: Basic, f: String) = {
    val im = cm.reflect(b)
    val member = im.symbol.typeSignature member newTermName(f)
    require(member != NoSymbol, s"No such member $f")
    (im reflectMethod member.asMethod)()
  }
}
case class Implic(p: Int) extends Basic {
  override protected val m = "some value"
}

object Test extends App {

  implicit class Copy[A <: Base](val b: A) {
    def overriding(overm: String): A = (b match {
      case impl: Impl => new Impl(impl.p) { override val m = overm }
      case b: Base    => new Base { override val m = overm }
    }).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
  implicit class Proxy[A <: Basic : ClassTag](val b: A) {
    def proximately(overm: String): Basic = new Basic {
      override val m = overm
      override def selectDynamic(f: String): Any =
        if ("m" == f) overm else reflecting(b, f)
      override def toString = b.toString
    }
  }

  // asked for this
  //def overriding[T <: Base](v: Base) = v.copy(m = "prefix" + v.m)

  /* want something like this
  def overriding[T <: Base](v: Base) = new Impl(v.p) {
    override val m = "some value"
  } */

  val a = Impl(5)
  val b = a overriding "bee good"
  Console println s"$a with ${a.m} ~> $b with ${b.m}"
  // or
  val c = Implic(7)
  val d = c proximately "dynomite"
  Console println s"$c with ${c.m} ~> $d with ${d.m}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will not consider the `copy` version. The `Dynamic`+`reflection` version is good but it seems that any access to d except d.m will have return type `Any` which is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Since traits don't get copy methods automatically, you can try using a `Base` case class instead:

```
  case class Base(toBeOverride: String)

  case class Impl(other: Int, someVal: String = "some value") extends Base(someVal)

  def overrideBaseValue[T <: Base](v: Base) =
      v.copy(toBeOverride = "prefix" + v.toBeOverride)
```

The problem that you're going to run into though, is that `copy` returns an instance of `Base` and I don't think that you can convert it back to your original `Impl` class. For instance, this won't compile:

```
  def overrideBaseValue[T <: Base](v: T): T =
      v.copy(toBeOverride = "prefix" + v.toBeOverride)
```

Comment: Also case class inheritance is deprecated.