# Is it possible to update fields of any case class implementing a common trait

Tags: scala, case-class, shapeless

Let's assume that we have a common trait Model.

```
trait Model {
  def id: String
  def updated: Date
}
```

And we have 2 case classes extending this trait.

```
case class C1(id: String, updated: Date, foo: String) extends Model
case class C2(id: String, updated: Date, bar: Int) extends Model
```

Is it possible to write a utility function like below which takes a Model as parameter and returns a copy with an updated value for the updated field?

```
object Model {
    def update[T <: Model](model: T): T = {
        model.copy(updated = new Date) // This code does not compile.
    }
}
```

Comment: [No](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12370244/298389)

Comment: @MilesSabin [I've seen that abstraction over arity was mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12492635/298389), but such overengineering is hardly a viable option (now, you can freely call me 'biased' or even a moron :-) ). Or there is some other way besides that?

Answer (score 4):

The "best" abstraction you can write here would be a `Lens` which looks like:

```
trait Lens[A, B]{
  def get: A => B
  def set: (A, B) => A
}
```

so that your code looks like:

```
def update[A](that: A, value: Date)(implicit tLens: Lens[A, Date]): A =
  tLens set (that, value)
```

Comment: A lens is good ... but I think we can probably _infer_ the lens given a shapeless `LabelledGeneric` for the case classes in question.

Comment: @MilesSabin Yes, I bet you're right. If you write it, I'll bump that answer up.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two issues:

1. `copy` is not defined on the trait, so you need to have something defined on the trait that you can use.
2. In order for `update` to return a `T` instead of a `Model`, every `Model` must know its actual subtype.

You can fix it like this:

```
trait Model[T <: Model[T]] {
  def id: String
  def updated: Date
  def withDate(d: Date): T
}

case class C1(id: String, updated: Date, foo: String) extends Model[C1] { def withDate(d: Date) = copy(updated = d) }
case class C2(id: String, updated: Date, bar: Int)    extends Model[C2] { def withDate(d: Date) = copy(updated = d) }

object Model {
  def update[T <: Model[T]](model: T): T = {
    model.withDate(new Date) // This code does not compile.
  }
}
```

So now it works:

```
scala> val c1 = C1("test", new Date, "foo")
c1: C1 = C1(test,Mon Apr 21 10:25:10 CDT 2014,foo)

scala> Model.update(c1)
res0: C1 = C1(test,Mon Apr 21 10:25:17 CDT 2014,foo)
```

Comment: This was the way I was planning to take. But I am still wondering if there is a way to do this automagically and type safe.

Comment: So even though `withDate` is the same line of code for every subtype of `Model` it needs to be rewritten for every class, correct?

Answer (score 1):

`copy` is a method defined on your case classes. Not on your base trait `Model`. What if you have that:

```
trait Model {
  def id: String
  def updated: Date
}

case class C1(id: String, updated: Date, foo: String) extends Model
case class C2(id: String, updated: Date, bar: Int) extends Model
class NotACaseClass(val id: String, val updated: Date) extends Model
```

`NotACaseClass` is a very valid child of `Model`, and you could pass an instance of it to your `update` function, but good luck finding a `copy` method :)

Comment: It answers *why it doesn't work* but provides no solution to the given problem.