# Correct usage of inheritance for wrapper classes

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a scala-wrapper for matrix operations, using the [ejml](http://ejml.org/) library. Basically I just use SimpleMatrix. However, I want different classes for matrix and vector, for example to only be able to invert a matrix or to explicitly state that a function returns a vector, not a matrix. Currently, I am having trouble returning the concrete classes instead of the trait.

I started with a trait, MLMatrixLike:

```
trait MLMatrixLike {
  def data: SimpleMatrix
  protected def internalMult(implicit that: MLMatrixLike): SimpleMatrix = {
    data.mult(that.data)
  }
  def *(implicit that: MLMatrixLike): MLVector = MLVector(internalMult)
}
```

Both my matrix class and my vector class are extending the trait:

```
case class MLMatrix(data: SimpleMatrix) extends MLMatrixLike {

  def this(rawData: Array[Array[Double]]) = this(new SimpleMatrix(rawData))

  def apply(row: Int, col:Int): Double = data.get(row, col)

  def transpose(): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data.transpose())

  def invert(): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data.invert())

  def *(implicit that: MLMatrix): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(internalMult)

  def *(that: Double): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data.scale(that))

  def -(that: MLMatrix): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data.minus(that.data))
}

object MLMatrix {
  def apply(rawData: Array[Array[Double]]) = new MLMatrix(rawData)
}

case class MLVector(data: SimpleMatrix) extends MLMatrixLike {

  def this(rawData: Array[Double]) = {
    this(new SimpleMatrix(Array(rawData)).transpose())
  }

  def apply(index: Int): Double = data.get(index)

  def transpose(): MLVector = MLVector(data.transpose())

  def -(that: MLVector): MLVector = MLVector(data.minus(that.data))
}

object MLVector {
  def apply(rawData: Array[Double]) = new MLVector(rawData)
}
```

To my mind, this setup is not very good. I would like to define multiply (*) only once, since the SimpleMatrix-call is always the same and I can infer from the type of the parameter "that" whether the return type should be a matrix or a vector. Thus I would like to define a single function in MLMatrixLike along the lines of this (not working) function:

```
def *[T <: MLMatrixLike](that :T): T = {
  new T(data.mult(that.data))
}
```

Of course, this does not work, since there is no such constructor T, but currently I fail to see, how I can get something similar to work. Returning MLMatrixLike is not correct to my mind, since that way I cannot check during compilation if the correct type is returned.

A similar problem applies to transpose, and minus - here the return type is always the own class.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the benefits of wrapping `SimpleMatrix` in two other classes are. However, you could solve the duplication problem by making `MLMatrixLike` generic with its self-type, and defining an abstract constructor.

```
trait MLMatrixLike[Self <: MLMatrixLike[Self]] {
  this: Self =>
  def data: SimpleMatrix

  def createNew(data: SimpleMatrix): Self

  def *[T <: MLMatrixLike[T]](that: T): T = that.createNew(data.mult(that.data))

  def *(that: Double): Self = createNew(data.scale(that))

  def -(that: Self): Self = createNew(data.minus(that.data))

  def transpose: Self = createNew(data.transpose())
}

case class MLMatrix(data: SimpleMatrix) extends MLMatrixLike[MLMatrix] {
  this: MLMatrix =>

  def this(rawData: Array[Array[Double]]) = this(new SimpleMatrix(rawData))

  override def createNew(data: SimpleMatrix): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data)

  def apply(row: Int, col: Int): Double = data.get(row, col)

  def invert(): MLMatrix = MLMatrix(data.invert())

}

object MLMatrix {
  def apply(rawData: Array[Array[Double]]) = new MLMatrix(rawData)
}

case class MLVector(data: SimpleMatrix) extends MLMatrixLike[MLVector] {
  this: MLVector =>

  def this(rawData: Array[Double]) = {
    this(new SimpleMatrix(Array(rawData)).transpose())
  }

  override def createNew(data: SimpleMatrix): MLVector = MLVector(data)

  def apply(index: Int): Double = data.get(index)

}

object MLVector {
  def apply(rawData: Array[Double]) = new MLVector(rawData)
}
```

By the way, note, that a column vector times a row vector is a matrix, so the signature of the multiplication should probably not return the type of `that`. However, based on static information (you need to know the dimensions of both arguments) you cannot tell whether a multiplication returns a vector or a matrix, so you may aswell just return a `MLMatrixLike`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Interestingly, since case-classes come with a `copy` method, you wouldn't even need to define  an abstract constructor in `MLMatrixLike`. Unfortunately you need some black magic to make `MLMatrixLike` aware of the `copy` method, hence it's more of a plaything. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12521080/4041697)