# Iteration over Scala tuples

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-collections

In scala, we can get an iterator over a tuple as follows

```
val t = (1, 2)
val it = t.productIterator
```

and even

```
it.foreach( x => println(x.isInstanceOf[Int]) )
```

returns true, we cannot do simple operations on the iterator values without using asInstanceOf[Int], since

```
it.foreach( x => println(x+1) )
```

returns an error: type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: String

I understand the issue with Integer vs. Int, but still the validity of isInstanceOf[Int] is somewhat confusing.

What is the best way to do these operations over tuples? Notice that the tuple can have a mix of types like integers with doubles, so converting to a list might not always work.

Comment: that question seems more about flattening a tuple of tuples

Comment: if you find yourself wanting to iterate over a tuple and apply a function to each value, it's generally a sign that you shouldn't be using a tuple in the first place. Tuples are not collections and you shouldn't try to use them as such.

Comment: Right, but sometimes you get tuples anyway like when reading from a database, and the simplest is to deal with them directly.

Comment: Well, it might not be simplest after all ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A tuple does not have to be homogenous and the compiler didn't try to apply magic type unification across the elements<sup>1</sup>*. Take `(1, "hello")` as an example of such a a heterogenous tuple (`Tuple2[Int,String]`).

This means that `x` is typed as `Any` (not `Int`!). Try `it.foreach( (x: Int) => println(x) )`, with the original tuple, to get a better error message indicating that the iterator is *not* unified over the types of the tuple elements (it is an `Iterators[Any]`). The error reported should be similar to:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int) => Unit
 required: (Any) => ?
       (1, 2).productIterator.foreach( (x: Int) => println(x) )
```

In this particular case `isInstanceOf[Int]` can be used to refine the type - from the `Any` that the type-system gave us - because *we* know, from manual code inspection, that it will "be safe" with the given tuple.

Here is another look at the iterators/types involved:

```
(1, 2)                         // -> Tuple2[Int,Int]
  .productIterator             // -> Iterator[Any]
  .map(_.asInstanceOf[Int])    // -> Iterator[Int]
  .foreach(x => println(x+1))
```

While I would recommend treating tuples as *finite sets of homogenous elements* and not a sequence, the same rules can be used as when dealing with any `Iterator[Any]` such as using pattern matching (e.g. `match`) that discriminates by the actual object type. (In this case the code is using an implicit PartialFunction.)

```
(1, "hello").productIterator
  .foreach {
    case s: String => println("string: " + s)
    case i: Int => println("int: " + i)
  }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> While it might be possible to make the compiler unify the types in this scenario, it sounds like a special case that requires extra work for minimal gain. Normally sequences like lists - not tuples - are used for homogenous elements and the compiler/type-system correctly gives us a good refinement for something like `List(1,2)` (which is typed as `List[Int]` as expected).

Comment: Thanks, I like the way you are doing the pattern matching to deal with this.

Comment: Pattern matching is indeed better style than `isInstanceOf` - that's why the latter has (on purpose) such an long and ugly name. It's better style because it unifies `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` in a less error-prone way.

Comment: the tuple's `productIterator` using `each` and `case` do the magic!  Thanks @user2246674

Answer (score 1):

There is another type HList, that is like tuple and List all-in-one. See [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

I think, you can get close to what you want:

```
import shapeless._
val t = 1 :: 2 :: HNil
val lst = t.toList
lst.foreach( x => println(x+1) )
```

Comment: If you already have a tuple, can you convert to HList directly without having to do the manual HList building?

Comment: I don't know. On stackoverflow there are plenty of HList questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapeless, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825129/are-hlists-nothing-more-than-a-convoluted-way-of-writing-tuples?rq=1 for instance).

Comment: I found: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/flatten.scala#L70 Yes you can convert tuples to HLists and vise versa.

Comment: @deepkimo: if you like some answer, make sure to accept it.