# Generic Extraction of Tuple's w/ Option[A]?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the function, `f`, which, given a 2-tuple of `Option[A]`'s, puts non-empty tuple elements into an output `List[A]`:

```
  def f[A](xs: (Option[A], Option[A])): List[A] = xs match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => List(x, y)
    case (None,    Some(y)) => List(y)
    case (Some(x), None)    => List(x)
    case (None,    None)    => List.empty
  }
```

How can I write a generic `f`, i.e. `fGen`, that will handle any tuple size, i.e. 2 to N?

Perhaps I can use shapeless?

Comment: You need to abstract over the arity of the tuple and this is one of things that Shapeless provides. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11826190/3248346

Comment: Do you have a use-case in mind? While I can see the interest as an intellectual exercise, it's difficult to see why one would want to use tuples of different sizes like this.  For your motivating example, as is common in (what I regard as) misuse of tuples, you're assuming a connection between different tuple elements that I don't think should be there (for example, in this case, that it makes sense for `(None, Some(y)`) and `(Some(x), None)` to return the same "shape" result (a single element list). Anyway, my opinion only.

Comment: Good point, @TheArchetypalPaul. No precise use case at the moment. I have a possible use case, but I need to flesh it out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my (*not* perfect) solution:

```
@ object Tuple2List {
    import shapeless._
    import syntax.std.tuple._
    import ops.hlist.ToTraversable
    trait Imp[A] {
      def apply[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)
               (implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L], 
                lub: LUBConstraint[L, Option[A]], 
                trav: ToTraversable.Aux[L, List, Option[A]]): List[A] =
        gen.to(p).toList.flatMap(_.toList)
    }
    def apply[A] = new Imp[A]{ }
  }
defined object Tuple2List
@ val xs = (Option(1), None, Option(2))
xs: (Option[Int], None.type, Option[Int]) = (Some(1), None, Some(2))

@ Tuple2List[Int](xs)
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
@ val ys = (Option(1), None, Option(2), None, Option(3))
ys: (Option[Int], None.type, Option[Int], None.type, Option[Int]) = (Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))
@ Tuple2List[Int](ys)
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Note that you need to **pass type parameter** `A` to make the scala compiler happy.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant of @Eastsun's solution which doesn't require a type parameter. Thanks to @Eastsun for pointing out that `list.map(ev)` can be used instead of a cast.

```scala
def tuple2list[P <: Product, L <: HList, Lub, A](p: P)(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L],
  toList: ToList[L, Lub],
  ev: Lub <:< Option[A]
): List[A] =
  gen.to(p).toList.map(ev).flatten

val xs = (Option(1), None, Option(2))
println(tuple2list(xs)) // List(1, 2)
```

Alternatively you can simply transform the `Product` to a `List` and apply `flatten` afterwards:

```scala
def tuple2list[P <: Product, L <: HList, Lub](p: P)(
  implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L],
  toList: ToList[L, Lub]
): List[Lub] =
  gen.to(p).toList

val xs = (Option(1), None, Option(2))
println(tuple2list(xs).flatten) // List(1, 2)
```

Comment: It seems than you can avoid using `asInstanceOf` via changing `asInstanceOf[List[Option[A]]`  to `map(ev)`

Answer (score 1):

The following code works with caveats:

can improve on

- make function `f` type safe (due to type erasure limited to `Option`)
- avoid casting using `asInstanceOf`

---

```
/**
 * param xs: Tuple of variable size (upto 22)
 */

def f[A](xs: Product): List[A] = xs.productIterator.toList.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Option[A]])

val tuple = (Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3))
f[Int](tuple) // List(1, 2, 3)
```