# Can ListBuffer[Any] retain the type of element?

Tags: scala

```
var buffer = new ListBuffer[Any]()

buffer += "Some Text"
buffer += 10
buffer += Some("text")
```

So, if I convert this ListBuffer to a list, it is not retaining the type.

```
scala> buffer.toList
res5: List[Any] = List(123, Some(abc))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The type is `Any`.  What type do you want to retain?

Comment: Yes, the type is retained. As your example demonstrates, if you start with `ListBuffer[X]` and apply `.toList` on it you'll get `List[X]`. No type information is lost in the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer` is a  `ListBuffer[Any]` from your declaration `new ListBuffer[Any]()`

When you convert buffer to a list, the same "inner type" is maintained, meaning you get a `List[Any]` from a `ListBuffer[Any]`

scala "native" collections don't support collections of unrelated types (String, Int, Option[X]), you get to lose important type information

A solution would be to use a tuple instead, if your variable is of finite length (a tuple of 2 elements has a different type of a tuple with 3 elements for instance)

Another solution is to use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) HList. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825129/are-hlists-nothing-more-than-a-convoluted-way-of-writing-tuples) is very good to explain what is an HList, why would you want one, and how to use