# How to store different types of input in an array in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

I am very new to Scala and was trying to understand how we can store values of different types in a collection.

For example, assuming I have the following values with corresponding types:

12 - `Int`
4.0 - `Float`
"is the best place to learn and practice coding!" - `String`

How can I store all the three inputs and perform different logic on each of them?

Comment: A great question & answer on the subject - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825129/are-hlists-nothing-more-than-a-convoluted-way-of-writing-tuples

Answer (score 6):

There is a bad answer: `Seq[Any]`. This is a sequence of any type, so you have no information about the members and will need to do a (potentially unsafe) cast or a (potentially non-exhaustive) pattern match again them.

There is a better answer: `HList`, which is a heterogeneous list, offered by the Shapeless library. This captures type information about each member. See an example [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/uniqueness.scala#L53).

There is a best answer: carefully consider whether you need this at all. `case class`es will tend to be more idiomatic *most of the time*.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> Array(12, 4.0f, "Hello")
res1: Array[Any] = Array(12, 4.0, Hello)

scala> res1.foreach{ case i: Int => println("Integer"); case f: Float => println("Float"); case s: String => println("String")}
Integer
Float
String
```

However - you should probably heed the advice given by @erip